# Create dynamic lists like ebay, amazon, etc.. using Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

What controls are used in Asp.net to display data such as amazon, ebay, etc? Each row consisting of picture(s), wors, hyperlinks, buttons, etc. Do they use DataGrid, Table, ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all going to depend on what you want. However, the control most likely to have the most flexibility and do exactly what you need it to will be the `<asp:Repeater/>` control.

Comment: Never used that one before. I'll check it out.

Comment: Ok. i've looked into it. so I have a dynamic table and thats what i want to use as datasource. So basically its all going to be dynamic from codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tejs has stated, I believe the most suitable control is an ASP.NET `Repeater` control as this only renders what is in the `ItemTemplate`:

http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

Unlike the `GridView` control which will render the content into an HTML `table`